# ORM: Sequelize: many to many relationship query

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

How do I query in many to many relationships? e.g. There are product, category, and product_category models. Below is an association by model:

```js
// product
product.belongsToMany (models.category, {
      through: 'product_category',
      foreignKey: 'product_id'
    });

// category
category.belongsToMany (models.product, {
      through: 'product_category',
      foreignKey: 'category_id'
    });

// product_category
product_category.belongsTo (models.product, {
      foreignKey: 'product_id'
    });
    product_category.belongsTo (models.category, {
      foreignKey: 'category_id'
    });
```

I would appreciate if you can tell me which model the `findAll ()` should have at the beginning when querying.

Comment: You should not need the belongsTo in product_category because you will never use that table as the base of a query.. that should not need associations set at all.. depending on which way you are requesting your data will depend where you set your findAll... if your page is looking for all the products in all category’s then use the findAll on category and have your schema include the associated product data for each category... not sure exactly how you are using sequelize, is it with GraphQL?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am still not good at using graphql and I am only using sequelize.

Are sequelize + graphql a good combination and are you using it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, seems like a good fit if you are using node and sequelize it’s a pretty simple lift to put GraphQL in play and manipulate your sequelize models in your resolvers... nice to have the graphiql playground to hit your queries with.... easy peazy

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. If I have any more questions, I will ask.

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help out where I can... Cheers